# Is it possible to have the return of a JS function depend on user action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have the return of a JS function depend on user action?

So let's say I have function a and function b.

Function b brings up a dialog with two buttons, one which returns true and one which returns false. Can I call b from a and force a to wait for the return from b before continuing it's operation?

Example code:

```
function a(){
    if(b()){
        do x
    }else{
        do y
    }
}

function b(){
$("#anElement").dialog({
    title: "This is a Dialog",
    buttons:{
        "Yes": function(){
            //do some stuff
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return true;
        },
        Cancel: function(){
            //do some stuff
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
}
```

I guess this is a lot like a confirm, but I want to build more than just yes / no on top of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe that `alert`-like dialogs halt execution so it would work for those, but for DOM dialogs like this it won't work.  Why not just use different button conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't halt a function's execution (well, you could with an infinite while loop with a break condition, but that's terrible practice). However, you could split A into two functions and call the other half of function A from function B. You could even pass in a return function to function B and call that, passing in the value of the user action.

**Example:**

```
function A() {
    // do stuff
    B(finishA);
}

function B(callback) {
    if(someCondition) {
        callback(true);
    } else {
        callback(false);
    }
}

function finishA(userInput) {
    if(userInput) {
        // do something if the user clicked okay
    } else {
        // do something if the user clicked cancel
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your calling the function not creating it?

Comment: @Jleagle: Not sure what you mean. That's the idea, isn't it? :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Your code was `function B(finishA);` which is syntactically invalid. Function invocation does not contain the `function` keyword, which is why I removed it.

Comment: Oh, woops, missed that. Thanks for the catch, @ŠimeVidas.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be...

```
function a () {
    b( function () {
        // do x           
    }, function () {
        // do y
    });
}

function b ( fn1, fn2 ) {
    $( "#anElement" ).dialog({
        title: "This is a Dialog",
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                //do some stuff
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                fn1();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                //do some stuff
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                fn2();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So, you pass two functions to `b`. The first one is invoked if the "Yes" button is activated, and the second function is invoked if the "Cancel" button is activated.

This pattern enables you to define the behavior directly inside the `a` function, instead of having to append it to the `b` function.